# SuppressWarnings in Java's for-each loop init?

Tags: java, generics, casting

In Java, how do I suppress unchecked cast warnings between the loop variable and the looped-upon variable?  e.g.,

```
// Actually a List<List<Integer>>
List<List> iterable = thirdPartyApiCallICantChange();
for(List<Integer> item : iterable) { ... }
```

The Java compiler complains that there is an unchecked cast happening at the at start of the "iterable" variable, but I can't figure out how to suppress it.

I've tried doing `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<Integer> item`, but the same error at the same place is reported.

I've tried casting `iterable` to a `List<List<Integer>>`, but I can't figure out how to; a normal `(List<List<Integer>>) iterable` doesn't seem to be accepted by the compiler.

Comment: Why are you using raw types? What do you mean by _Actually a Lis...._?

Comment: The third party APIs I'm using are somewhat complicated and don't allow expressing things cleanly, so I'm stuck with them returning a list of lists, and then having to pull stuff out manually.

Comment: What are you doing with `item`? That is, what's in the for loop. You should be handling the lack of type information there, not suppressing the warning.

Comment: Is the return type of `thirdPartyApiCallICantChange` `List<List>`?

Comment: Add the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the containing method.

Comment: Cast when assigning to `iterable`, as in: `@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" }) List<List<Integer>> iterable = (List)thirdPartyApiCallICantChange();`. Now the `for` loop won't have any warnings.

Comment: @Andreas thank you! I couldn't figure out to properly cast generics. If you post an answer, I'll accept it so you can get the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast when assigning to `iterable`, as in:

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
List<List<Integer>> iterable = (List)thirdPartyApiCallICantChange();
```

Now the `for` loop won't have any warnings.